# Shell user input length limitation

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, ksh

There is a simple shell (does not matter sh, bash or KornShell (ksh)) script:

```
#!/bin/ksh

read userInput
```

I have two Solaris 9/10 servers. On one of the server I can type long string while read is running. But on another server I can't type string with length more than 257 symbols.

What kind of limitation is this?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably the terminal input queue size limitation, `MAX_INPUT` constant is the maximum size of that queue.

Can't exactly remember but kernels can be customized (settings) to handle new values for such constant. Refer to your system kernel config documentation.

Comment: strange because when i execute command "read userInput" from command line there is no such length limit.

Comment: You're right that is very strange. I have no Solaris under my hands at that time. There is may be a side effect with the terminal mode. Look if the `stty` modes are different or not, this may be the key...